# Should I change the accepted answer of a post to fit other people's questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

This has by far been my most popular question [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain) and the Accepted Answer is the one which correctly answered my specific question (as it mentioned my exact scenario of changing my URL)...

However it seems that most people are brought to my question with a slightly different issue, solved by the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200021/895810) with a highest vote count, as google searching for '*laravel the domain of the url isn't included in the app's domain*' (at the time of this posting) has my posting as the #1 result.

Since it appears many more people are helped by [This Second Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200021/895810) should I change it to be the accepted answer so it will be more visible and also show up in Google's search result summary of the posting?

One person [even mentioned in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain#comment63169680_37200021) not seeing the second answer until much later.

Comment: The best option—in my own opinion, others undoubtedly disagree—would be to not select an answer, and let the best answer win out over time through the natural process of voting.

Comment: This is a good example of why there needs to be at the very least an option to not count acceptance when filtering by votes....

Comment: No, the check mark is meant to indicate which answer most/best helped the OP. It especially doesn't make sense to change the accepted answer when other people are apparently having a different problem than the one described in your question. It's one thing to not accept answers on your new questions, it's another to indicate that an answer best helped you when that's not true.

Comment: @BSMP, I think you're totally right. the person who posted the accepted answer was doing so to answer the OP's original question. The other subsequent answers (while useful) we're written with as much intent to answer the original question, and therefore (again while useful) aren't the 'correct' answer.  (Plus, if someone hasn't learned to read all the answer's before moving on......)

Comment: I'd probably edit something into the top of the question along the lines of bold "NOTE: the accepted answer is the one that worked for my particular situation with Facebook but if you're here because of a more generic Laravel error, check the other answers" - though equally the advice to remove the tick seems sensible - it removes the "beacon of focus" at little rep penalty if the answer is popular

Comment: I don't think your accepted answer is broken, I think google is broken.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could ask-and-answer the problem with the second answer's solution, and not have it marked as a duplicate :o)

Comment: If you feel particularly generous, one option is to start a bounty and award it to the non-accepted answer. That will make it more visible and I have seen people do this before when there were two good answers. You could do a bounty as low as 50 rep.

Comment: I tend to think that if you accepted an answer that solved the problem at the time you asked it, there's no reason to change it because others found a different answer helpful to them. The original answer was written for you, not others, by someone volunteering their time to help you. Why should they now be punished (by losing the accept and related reputation points) because of what someone else did that *others* found useful later? If the second answer was posted at the same time, you accept the first and then a short time see the second that works better, that's one thing. Much later...?

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think length of time is all that important when it comes to accepted answers. Sure, it stings the ego a bit to lose that check mark and the rep. If an answer that is truly more useful to the OP comes later it's still their prerogative to change it if they want to. Of course, accepting an answer "too quickly" is another matter.

Comment: @BoogaRoo: Certainly it does. The accepted answer is supposed to be chosen by the poster as the one that was most helpful. If someone writes an answer that meets that criteria, and the accept is awarded to them, they've earned it (unless someone comes along shortly after and provides a better solution). However, if someone comes along 6 months later, the problem has already been solved (the poster accepted), and that poster has moved on to other things. Unless the new answer is *vastly superior*,  the original should still stay the accepted one IMO; the answerer who got it solved the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite Oh, I agree. I've lost the accept mark on an answer almost a year after after the OP selected my answer. When I went back and looked, the new answer was indeed honestly that much better. It is rare, but it does happen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's totally up to you to decide which answer helps **you** the most, or you preferred over other solutions. Votes will help others see the rest of the answers. Hopefully all the answers on a question are helpful to people who find it, regardless of their own reasons for finding it.

This isn't exactly uncommon. I've had something similar happen where the OP told me my answer was correct and solved the question that was asked. However, he accepted an answer that basically told him "Don't do that, do this other thing instead." While I understand the other answer didn't "answer" the question as stated, it answered the OP's underlying need. If people who find the question need either answer, both are there and marked accordingly. My answer has more votes, but that doesn't matter to the OP, and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

No you shouldn't. Edit your question so it's not easily confused with the other question, and then address the other question in another post and answer it. This way both questions have an easy to search solution.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Booga Roo's answer. In addition, as I stated in [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361120/should-i-change-the-accepted-answer-of-a-post-to-fit-other-peoples-questions?cb=1#comment542871_361120),
if you feel particularly generous, one option is to start a bounty and award it to the non-accepted answer. That will make it more visible and I have seen people do this before when there were two good answers. You could do a bounty as low as 50 rep.

Note that no one expects you to do this. This was just a suggestion if you feel the non-accepted answer is valuable as well.

Comment: Yes, the blue bounty reward icon may give a hint that it has been a best answer. But as it's already the most upvoted answer, a bounty will not make a big difference for reputation.

Answer (score -9):

I think you should leave the accepted answer as is, but make an edit to the question that explains your questions was answered by #1, but for others reading in the future #2 might be more helpful for them.

Comment: Editing meta information into a post is a big no-no. The question should be _just_ the question, and nothing about what answers the question.

Comment: @Kendra [citation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: @Kendra wouldn't this qualify as "To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)". E.g. having your edit literally say: "I meant A, but others reading this might be looking for B which also has a good answer below."

Comment: No, not in the slightest. That would be clarifying meta information about the answers posted to the question, not the question being asked. The question is for the question part, the answers are for the answer part, and comments are for the commentary part.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I don't see anything in that link that says you should edit commentary about answers into a question.

Comment: @Kendra I was pointing out nowhere in "How to Edit" does it say what you've said. I would say it falls under the spirit of editing "[t]o include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place". While I might agree that generally you shouldn't do so, there are exceptions to every rule, and in this case breaking your unwritten rule leads to better communication. One of the fundamental goals of writing good questions is making them useful for future readers. That goal outweighs any rule against it for me.

Comment: I suggest you search carefully around meta, @TemporalWolf. That is not a rule I came up with, it's what I've learned after a long time on Meta.

Comment: If there was evidence that people were being mislead by my question, clarification is absolutely justified. I'm somewhat baffled by the suggestion that helping to direct future readers is somehow incongruent with the SO mission.

Comment: @Kendra I've asked the question [directly to MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361184/3579910). Feel free to include your input if you'd like.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I'm just being pedantic right now (so pay no mind), but the past-tense verse of mislead is misled.

Comment: @TinyGiant My apologies for my typo which butchered the Queen's English.

Answer (score -21):

Why not rewrite your question to be what people are looking for, accept that answer, post a new question that asks your specific problem, and post the answer that worked for you (etiquette should be to comment on it asking the original answerer to copy their answer to the new question so they get the points). Then edit each question to link to the other one "if you want this, then this is the question you are looking for...").

Basically you have two questions (by no fault of your own) mashed into one. Fork them. Let them live separately lives. This is the best approach for the utility of the site as a resource. Perhaps an admin could even help make it neat and carry scores, but you can hand bomb it yourself.

Comment: If forking, it would make more sense to retain the existing question and accepted answer. The *new* question can be about what others are looking for.

Comment: A question should never be edited to invalidate existing answers.