# Should questions be edited with meta information to direct future readers?

Tags: discussion

In [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361153/3579910) to a recent meta question, the suggestion was made to edit in clarification to a question in order to draw readers attention to a non-accepted answer which, while it doesn't address the OP's question, is the answer for most of the readers of the question.

This suggestion has been general received unfavorably, as it conflates the question with commentary or meta information. I disagree, as it appears to me to fall under ["[y]ou edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/344593).

While a third party editor may have trouble ensuring that they don't change the meaning, the OP (as was the original asker in the referenced question) will not have this issue.

So would this or would this not be in line with community standards?

To be clear, I envision this as something along the lines of:

> This question is specifically addressed towards widgets. If you're
>   having problems with gadgets, [this may end up more helpful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361184/3579910)

Comment: Can someone explain why so many down casts on this question? Not obvious why for me.

Answer (score 14):

No, that is not how the system was designed to be used, and no it should not be used that way.

As a wise man once said:

> The question is for the question part, the answers are for the answer part, and comments are for the commentary part. – Tiny Giant [18 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361120/should-i-change-the-accepted-answer-of-a-post-to-fit-other-peoples-questions/361153#comment542884_361153)

Comment: Very wise indeed! I didn't even have to use the force to get yo... I mean, that wise man to post an answer. :P

Comment: Preferably you'd have a source other than yourself, on the question in question, to cite. I don't find it at all hard to believe you'd agree with yourself, but it doesn't exactly lend credibility to the answer.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Why are you surprised that when you ask the exact same question a second time you get the exact same answer?  It's not our fault you didn't like the answer the first time you got it, nor is that a reason for it to change.

Comment: @Servy I didn't post the original answer referenced, so I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to. I linked back to this post specifically so TinyGiant and Kendra could voice their disagreement: I am more interested whether the greater MSO community agrees or disagrees with them.

Comment: @TemporalWolf that is generally shown through voting, which also tends to account for the credibility of such answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree, and I'm not invalidating the vote, which it's pretty clear agrees with you. That determination is what I was after, after all. That being said, I'd still be interested in supporting citations if you have them.

Comment: Not off-hand. I mean, basically years of experience participating in, contributing to, and aiding in the moderation of the Stack Overflow and Meta communities alamgamated into a belief/values system that I use to evaluate situations and interactions. Not really something I can reference. @TemporalWolf

Comment: If nothing else comes of this, at least now you'll have something to point to in the future :)

Comment: @TemporalWolf You had that before you even posted the question, with the post that you linked to.

Comment: @Servy with a net vote on that suggestion of -1 or 0 (+/- ~4)? Since then, it's gone more negative (no doubt [because I linked it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/3579910)), but it was nearly flat when I created this question.

Comment: Some meta-commentary provides important context and makes the answers to the question clearer to everybody involved. The comments are tiny little footnotes that a lot of people will never bother to read.

Answer (score 4):

The *only* potential information about answers that should be put in a question is what has already been tried- And that would only include existing answers on *other* questions, to show the question is not a duplicate.

We have parts labeled very clearly. Indicating that an answer fits a different situation is *not* clarifying the question- It's ***clarifying the answer.***

As Tiny Giant said, in both the comments on the answer you link and in [his answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361185/2607247):

> The question is for the question part

The line you quote does not mean you should clarify *answers* in the question.